# knockout js add / remove css class within ko.utils.arrayForEach

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have a loop as below:

```
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(res , function(mail) {

      if(mail.isRead === true)
       //Then i need to remove the class "unread"
      else if (mail.isRead === false)
       //Then i need to add the class unread
      ........//other logic
      });
```

In Frontend ,

```
    <tr class="unread" data-bind="">                 
     <td><dl>

     <dd><a data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="" data-bind="text:personid"></a</dd>

     </dl></td>
     </tr>
```

How can i add/remove class unread based on my isRead field within the forEach loop ? Any help for this appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jquery:

```
$('selector').addClass('unread')
```

However the better solution would be to add a css binding:

```
data-bind="css : {'unread' : person.hasUnread}
```

Comment: To be clear that data-bind needs to be added onto your anchor tag after the text property or somewhere inside of the foreach.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How can i do the corresponding logic in my knockout viewmodel?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the required output :)